# Are there costumes/locations from the X-Men comics in season 2?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, legion

[According to this interview](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/08/03/legion-season-2-x-men-comics-connections-costumes-hair/), season 2 of Legion would have costumes/locations from the X-Men comics. I am not familiar with the comics.

What costumes/locations have shown up? There are only 2 episodes left.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if the interview means that quite as literally, as one could take it, but the following are some **X-Men Easter Eggs** from the second season (so far).

1. In episode 2.01 Cary Loudermilk namedrops **Shi'ra**, an alien Race known in Marvel comics & X-Men (introduced in X-Men #97), most notoriously apart of [Dark Phoenix Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Phoenix_Saga), which **Dark Phoenix** also featured in an upcoming X-Men film. In addition their Empress, Lilandra, was once married to Charles Xavier in one of the timelines. In *Legion* (The TV series, like the comic) Charles Xavier is David's father.
2. In Episode 2.01 Ptonomy Mentions **"The Lazarus Affair"** & uses the phrase, ***'new mutants'***. (New Mutants is also another upcoming X-Men film featuring characters from New Mutants comics) **Lazarus** is the name of a character who is part of a genetic weapons program, and who was thought too dangerious and should cease to exist. The character's sister is **Domino**, who is currently featured in *Deadpool 2*, whom is also referenced in *Legion* season 2 during a Division 3 sequence featuring a numbering system that is done like **domino patterns** instead of numerals. The plot of season 2 of *Legion* is in part a debate being shown through parallel universes if either David, more than The Shadow King, needs to die for the world to be safe, both, or neither?
3. Beehive aesthic/motif of Division 3 playing to General Fukuyama's beehive-mind androids, The Vermillion, seems completely **opposite to an "X" motif**.
4. David at one point says, "Boost my signal!", which could be a reference to Charles Xavior and **Cerebro**.
5. In 2.02 Kerri Loudermilk has a **"Rogue" hair streak**. Rogue also had an Aunt named Carrie.
6. The Vermillion are the name given to Fukuyama's androids. In some ways they could be seen as succesors to **the Sentinals in *Days of Future Past***, which like *Legion* season 2, is playing with multiple universe to possibly change the time line (ie: Future Syd + 2.06 multiple universes). They also are like the **Cuckoos** too, which are currently featured at the end of season 1 of *The Gifted*. *The Gifted* also is borrowing elements from *Days of Future Past* and like *Legion* takes place in another time line/universe from the main X-Men films.
7. As mentioned, epsiode 2.06 features a few alternate parallel universes. In one, David has **a standoff with Police**, similar to **Magneto** in the X-Men films.
8. In episode 2.10 David is seen **wearing a black and orange outfit** reminiscent to his comic counterpart in *X-Men: Legacy* run.

**Here are some links to some sources:**
https://www.gamespot.com/gallery/all-the-x-men-easter-eggs-and-references-in-legion/2900-1957/

https://www.bustle.com/p/the-marvel-easter-eggs-in-legion-season-2-link-its-trippy-world-to-deadpool-the-new-mutants-8671018

---

**NOTE:** If I find or remember more, I will comeback and update.

**Addiitonal X-Men Stuff:**

Some of these easter eggs, including a lot of beautifully filmed desert scenes, such as The Shadow King and David & Syd searching for his body, also adds up to referencing the **[Age of Apocalypse](http://marvel.com/universe/Shadow_King_(Age_of_Apocalypse)#axzz5HBzt5dKY) storyline** (and by extension the X-Men film, ***Apocalypse***),as the Shadow King, being from Egypt and being as old as the dawn of man, becomes an agent of the character **Apocalypse**, who is then used to hunt down other telepaths. This storyline also includes **Domino**.

[image: Strom & Apocalypse]

In addition, besides figuring into one backstory of Professor X, the Shadow King also (in the comics) figures into the backstory of the character **Storm**. Storm is a character whose power is shown by a **change in her eyes**. During *Legion's* second season (2.05) The Shadow King takes Lenny Busker up on her request to require a new a body, in which he

> exorcizes David's sister Amy's conscious from her body.

The results are that Lenny looks like herself, except she has *that* character's eyes! In episode 2.09 the character goes to out to use her new body, and there is a song by Nicolas Jaar titled, *Space is Only Noise If You Can See* with lyrics, *"You used to check **the weather**, now you stopped that"*. Storm's powers are about summoning thunderstorms and using their **electrical power**. This episode also features a couple of **"electric"** themes,

> from an electric sign and place called The Blue Octopus and a blue
>  vintage car teleporting from the Blue Octopus parking lot to the
>  desert.

Although it's true *Legion* has nautical themes/motifs in which the Blue Octopus fits into, the word Octopus has similar letters and sounds to the word apocalypse AND one plot feautures an **end of the world scenario** seemingly coming from a character from the future of the current timeline, taking to a couple of the main *legion* characters to try and change said future.